# Problem making a website running on Windows visible on Amazon EC2

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2

I just launched an instance of Windows server 2008 on Amazon EC2.

This instance is in a security group allowing RDP and HTTP. Here are the allowed connections on this instance

```
"Connection Method" Protocol "From Port" "To Port" "Source (IP or group)" 
RDP                 tcp      3389         3389     0.0.0.0/0    
HTTP                tcp      80           80       0.0.0.0/0
```

I installed tomcat on this server on port 80. I can connect using rdp to the machine, and,  using its local Internet Explorer, I can view the welcome page of tomcat on http://localhost

Now, I would like to see this from  outside the amazon network, but when I connect to the public DNS of my instance, something looking like :

```
ec2-*************.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I get no response. Any idea on how to troubleshoot this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the Windows firewall on the instance?